# SSH to a system after jenkins pipeline is executed

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any
     tools{
        jdk 'JDK 1.8'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Clean') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'mvn clean'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Install'){
            steps{
                script{
                    sh 'mvn install'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy'){
            steps{
                script{
                    sh 'mvn deploy'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when this pipeline is executed i want to ssh to a system and use a .ppk file as cred which is stored on my host machine, below is the command to ssh for your refernce

```
ssh -i "{path to ppk file}" ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Also when i do mvn install i get a .war file in jenkins logs whose path i want to access in order to deploy.

```
aws s3 --profile abc cp <war s3 path> abc.war
```

Please help me do that :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        jdk 'JDK 1.8'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Clean') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'mvn clean'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Install') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'mvn install'
                }
                // Archive the .war file generated by Maven
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/*.war', fingerprint: true
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Add your SSH key to the SSH agent
                    sshagent(credentials: ['<your-ssh-credential-id>']) {
                        // SSH to the EC2 instance and deploy the .war file
                        sh 'scp -i xyz.pem target/*.war ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/path/to/deployment/directory'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        jdk 'JDK 1.8'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Clean') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'mvn clean'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Install') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'mvn install'
                }
                // Archive the .war file generated by Maven
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/*.war', fingerprint: true
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Add your SSH key to the SSH agent
                    sshagent(credentials: ['<your-ssh-credential-id>']) {
                        // SSH to the EC2 instance and deploy the .war file
                        sh 'scp -i xyz.pem target/*.war ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/path/to/deployment/directory'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i normally follow this,you can use the sshagent plugin to temporarily add your SSH key (xyz.pem) to the SSH agent and then execute SSH commands to connect to your EC2 instance.

Comment: I have cred as a .ppk file stored on my host machine

Comment: @AkshatManiTripathi unless you're running Jenkins on your local machine, Jenkins doesn't have access to that .ppk. You need to create a credential of type "SSH Username with private key", and use the .ppk file content for the "Private key' part. Then you can use the `sshagent` like this answer has shown. I'd advise to give the credential an ID that's explains its purpose; don't leave it empty or you'll have to work with some auto-generated value.

Comment: Hi, @RobSpoor this jenkins is running inside a docker container, and that is container is running on my host machine, will it work?

Comment: @AkshatManiTripathi it could work with some work. First you need to make sure the ppk file is present in the Docker image (mount its directly somewhere). Next you need to tell Jenkins to use that file. Unfortunately `sshagent` only works with existing credentials, so you'll need to setup scp manually. I _think_ that you can add `-i <path-to-ppk-file>`, but I think you first need to convert the ppk file to something that `scp` understands.

Comment: I managed to get it work by converting a ppk file to a private key using the steps described in https://superuser.com/a/232365. I did have to enter my passphrase twice: once when converting the ppk file, once while using `scp`.

Comment: When I said "mount its directly" I meant "mount its directory"